# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/StringContext

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

Scala, Play in CentOS

I'm not totally sure how to explain this error, because I'm diving head first into a framework I don't know much about. But if it is a common error, someone here should be able to help me.

Basically, I'm trying to "play" a project, and I get this error. What's the problem, some direction please.

http://pastebin.com/WqdNHNF1

Comment: Does your project depends(including trasitive depencies) on other scala version? Myabe you shall post build.sbt file

Comment: build.sbt: http://pastebin.com/qP6Xzcw1

Comment: You may use `play dependencies` to check whether there are incompatible dependencies

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EQXs0nj3 What do you think?

Comment: Ok, what aoubnt project/plugins.sbt

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y7mwhARQ :)

Comment: You may download fresh play distribution(2.2.3), and type `play new <project-name>` to create brand new project and have a try. Or just `export SBT_OPTS=-verbose:class` in console and then to see the loaded jar and class to check the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You might be compiling it with the wrong version of play.